# FlatList is not showing anything in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I do have such kind of JSON. I am getting it on my React Native app.

```
order:[
    {
    "id": "00005497",
    "order_number": "525522",
    "order_result_json": [
      {
        "key": "Номер",
        "value": "25263640253590"
      },
      {
        "key": "Ссылка на скачивание",
        "value": "https://play.google.com/store/"
      },
      {
        "key": "Ссылка на лицензию",
        "value": "https://google.com"
      }
    ]
}]
```

I can see that data is coming: alert(JSON.stringify(order.orderResultJson)); this is showing that array is coming.

When I am applying it to my FlatList, it is showing empty space, and if I scrolling page down it is going infinite scroll with empty content.

**My FlatList implementation:**

```
<View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
     <FlatList
           data={order.orderResult}
           renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.value}+5</Text>} 
           keyExtractor={item => item.key} 
      />   
</View>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't just a typo?

Your code uses `data={order.orderResult}`, but your json data contains `order_result_json`, and your debugging code with alert uses `orderResultJson`

Comment: Yes it was typo mistake.

Comment: data={order.orderResultJson} it should be like this

Answer (score 0):

**order** is an array, so you cannot access **order.orderResult**.

2 solutions :

- Use the first item of the **order** array : **order[0].orderResult**
- Change the structure of the **order** object (why is it an array?)